# Problems with git branches

Tags: git, branch, commit, pull

I submitted code to a github project through a git pull and it worked fine : https://github.com/ivaldi/brimir/pull/245

Now I am submitting new changes, but the pull also include all the commits from the previous pull : https://github.com/ivaldi/brimir/pull/257

The maintainer want me to clean the commits before he merge, but how do I do that?

EDIT : one thing i do not understand is that in my pull request, i have commits with hash that already exist in the master branch. How do i make my submit aware that thoses commits are already in the master?

EDIT 2 : I think Iknow where the problem come from, I pulled the change from my first change from my branch because they were not yet accepted in the master. I also pulled the change from master origin from my first branch, so now it want to push thoses already existing commits to origin master.

Comment: You don't mean *I submitted code to a github project through a git pull*, but *github pull request*; that's two different things.

Comment: What do you mean by `clean the commits`? If the initial pull request (assuming you mean pull request for `git pull`) is not merged, then newly pushed commits will also get added in the old pull request.

Comment: I think it mean not resubmitting the commits that are already in the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is submit a pull request for a branch off of `master` that contains only the new commits, i.e. those commits that were not in your last pull request. Let's say the last commit of your previous pull request was commit `A`, and that the branch with your latest changes is `add_users_crud_to_api`. In that case, you want to:

1. Make sure your fork has the latest version of `master`. See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) if you are unsure of how to do that.
2. Create a new branch that points to the same commit as the one with your latest changes: `git branch newbranchname add_users_crud_to_api`.
3. Replay all the new commits onto `master`: `git rebase --onto master A newbranchname` (remember, `A` is whatever the last commit of your successful pull request was).

Now `newbranchname` will be branched off of master, and only contain the new commits (i.e. the ones for this next pull request). So you can go ahead and push it and do your pull request with that branch.

### EDIT 1

OK, so out of curiosity I took a look at your repo and I noticed that for some reason you have merged `master` into your feature branch (`add_users_crud_to_api`). Rebasing doesn't really play well with merges (and the merge should not have been performed anyway). As far as I can tell, there are only 2 new commits you need in your pull request, so I would just cherry-pick them:

1. `git checkout master -b add_users_crud_to_api2`
2. `git cherry-pick ef9f73d`
3. `git cherry-pick eabcdc6`

Then you can submit a pull request for `add_users_crud_to_api2`.

Comment: The rebase modify too many files i do not know, i will create a new repo with the master and apply my changes again even if your solution seems the more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> The maintainer want me to clean the commits before he merge, but how do I do that?

Obvious answer: ask the maintainer, not us.

Other obvious answer: Make a commit that is as clean as you possible; i.e. make the changes from the current state of the branch you want the maintainer to pull in your changes (master, probably), and not your own, modified code.

Comment: In the commits there is changes i pulled from the master, how do i declare that i do not want to resubmit them?

Answer (score 0):

> The maintainer want me to clean the commits before he merge, but how do I do that?

You should do a squash

---

In order to do a git squash follow those steps:

```
// X is the number of commits you wish to squash, in your case 6
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `s` for squash = it will combine all the commits into a single commit.

[image]

---

You also have the `--root` flag in case you need it

try: `git rebase -i --root`

**--root**

```
Rebase all commits reachable from <branch>, instead of limiting them with
an <upstream>.

This allows you to rebase the root commit(s) on a branch.  
When used with --onto, it will skip changes already contained in `<newbase>`   
(instead of `<upstream>`) whereas without --onto it will operate on every 
change. When used together with both --onto and --preserve-merges, all root 
commits will be rewritten to have `<newbase>` as parent instead.`
```